# Getting started with QTip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip2

I'm trying to use Qtip to add tooltips to a site I'm working on, but for the life of me, I can't get it to do anything! I tried posting my question in the qtip forums but have gotten no reply, so I want to try here instead.
I've created a simple webpage to get the general syntax down, but even that isn't working.
Here's the HTML for the test page.

```
<html>

<head>
<title> test </title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="qtip/jquery.qtip.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qtip/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qtip/imagesloaded.pkg.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="box" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px;">Here's the div</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here's the code for the .JS file.

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('#box').qtip({
         content: 'Mouse tracking! Content'
     });
 });
```

I just want cool tooltips for my page to work quickly and easily T_T
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Are you able to verify that the qtip libraries are in the correct location?

Comment: Yeah, I checked out the script imports using FIreBug, and the libraries were all there. I found that my CSS library was originally not directed correctly, but I fixed that. That fix, however, made my scroll over go from looking crappy to completely disappearing, so I dunno what's up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#box').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Mouse tracking! Content'
    }
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gtf8yr/2/)**

Comment: I mean, a tool tip is being displayed on the bottom left corner, but it doesn't go away on mouseout and it doesn't have any default formatting attached :-\

Comment: THAT! How did you do that? Your code looks no different!

Comment: It worked well for my test page, but it's not migrating so smoothly. >_>